# Why wont my autocomplete stay?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

I've got this lines of codes to help me auto-complete a text box. It does suggest but before I select, it disappears within 2 seconds. How do I get it to stay until i select an option?

```
        void autoComplete()
    {
        searchTxtBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        searchTxtBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Cmanager;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from NEWMEMBER", con);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (nameRadBtn.Checked) 
                { 
                string databaseAuto = (reader["Surname"].ToString());
                coll.Add(databaseAuto);
                }
                if (idRadBtn.Checked)
                {
                    string databaseAuto = (reader["MemberID"].ToString());
                    coll.Add(databaseAuto);
                }
                if (deptRadBtn.Checked)
                {
                    string databaseAuto = (reader["DeptID"].ToString());
                    coll.Add(databaseAuto);
                }

            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        searchTxtBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coll;
    }

    private void searchTxtBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        autoComplete();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `TextChanged()` event instead of `KeyUp`. Also you don't need to bind `AutoComplete source` prior to use like this. But set `textbox` properties before using auto complete and use a field variable for `AutoCompleteStringCollection`

try this solution,

```
  // Private field
  private AutoCompleteStringCollection coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

  public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
        ....
        searchTxtBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        searchTxtBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
  }

    void autoComplete()
       {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Cmanager;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from NEWMEMBER", con);
            SqlDataReader reader;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (nameRadBtn.Checked) 
                    { 
                    string databaseAuto = (reader["Surname"].ToString());
                    coll.Add(databaseAuto);
                    }
                    if (idRadBtn.Checked)
                    {
                        string databaseAuto = (reader["MemberID"].ToString());
                        coll.Add(databaseAuto);
                    }
                    if (deptRadBtn.Checked)
                    {
                        string databaseAuto = (reader["DeptID"].ToString());
                        coll.Add(databaseAuto);
                    }

                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

     private void searchTxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
     {
         col.clear() // Clear older entries
         autoComplete();
         searchTxtBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coll;
     }
```

Comment: Thank you @KCdod. Did what you asked plus a few other rearrangements and it works fine.